# memory management Dead store in the static analyzer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have lunched the Static analyzer in my app and i have some warnings (errors) and i don't know how to avoid theme, the warnings are :

```
Dead store ....
```

the code line is :

```
NSArray *listHighlights = [NSArray array];
 listHighlights = [jsonParser objectWithString:highlightText error:&error];
....
```

I think that i can do like this, but the object `listHighlights` is not allocate ??

```
NSArray *listHighlights = [jsonParser objectWithString:highlightText error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
NSArray *listHighlights = [NSArray array];
```

...makes your variable point to an autoreleased array, and you then immediately overwrite the address of that object with whatever is returned from `objectWithString:`...presumably another array that **it** has created.  Because of the autorelease, it's not actually a leak but it's certainly a waste of effort.

Comment: Can i do something like this : NSArray *listHighlights = [jsonParser objectWithString:highlightText error:&error]; ??

Comment: It depends on what `objectWithString:` actually returns but, in theory, yes.